# How to make a block fixed and float in flexbox display?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have three blocks in body.

1. Title bar
2. content block
3. Bottom block

I have used flex display for body.

I want to make the title bar float ie., should remain in top when scrolling.
I tried css property `float:left;` for title bar block...

But its not working....
I need an idea to solve this problem..

Comment: `float` property doesn't mean the title bar will _float above the rest of the document_. You probably want to use `position: fixed`. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: @matewka Sorry thats my blender!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want the title bar to be fixed to the top, you will need to use:

```
left:0;
position:fixed;
top:0;
```

The float attribute is to actually float an element to the left or right, not to fix their position. It should be used sparingly if at all.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using `position: fixed` on the title.

Here's a js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/uctzS/1/